# NoSuchProviderException for java mail api

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail

I created a simple maven project in eclipse in order to send some emails with one personal gmail account. In eclipse, the mail was successfully sent. Then I built the project into an executable jar with dependencies. However, when I run the jar from the command line, it throws the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
    at EmailSender.send(EmailSender.java:75)
    at EmailSender.createNewAccount(EmailSender.java:33)
    at EmailSender.main(EmailSender.java:18)
Caused by: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
    at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:792)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:728)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:668)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:648)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:705)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:248)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at EmailSender.send(EmailSender.java:73)
    ... 2 more
```

Does anyone know what's the difference between executing the program inside Eclipse, and the jar outside ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by modifying the pom.xml, so it could exports all dependencies. The trick is to remove the line

```
<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
```

in the following code

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>*******</groupId>
    <artifactId>**********</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/shaded</outputDirectory>
                            <finalName>d2si-mailsender</finalName>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>EmailSender</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: but what if you want the jar to be minimal? Can you somehow force include certain files?

Answer (score 0):

you should have a services folder in your META-INF folder with all the provider files and you should export them to the jar also. eclipse includes them by default, but an exported jar is not

Comment: Exactly.  See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704125/read-gmail-inbox-using-javamail-works-in-eclipse-but-not-outside), which is likely the same underlying problem.